# Replacing TabActivity by Fragment : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I've seen that I have a common error judging by the number of similar questions asked on this forum, but I haven't found any answer in these.

I try to use fragments in order to replace the deprecated tabActivity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MediaActivity extends FragmentActivity{

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.psa_media);
        }
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment"
        android:id="@+id/tabs_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've also tried to replace android:name by class

Here is my logCat :

```
02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{fr.partisocialiste.psa/fr.partisocialiste.psa.activity.MediaActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
> inflating class fragment 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 02-09 10:07:48.738:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 02-09 10:07:48.738:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 02-09 10:07:48.738:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 02-09 10:07:48.738:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-09 10:07:48.738:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1713): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> fr.partisocialiste.psa.activity.MediaActivity.onCreate(MediaActivity.java:14)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   ... 18 more 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713): Caused by:
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
> instantiate fragment fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment: make
> sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that
> is public 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:332) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:300) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   ... 27 more 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713): Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment in loader
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/fr.partisocialiste.psa-1.apk]
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
> 02-09 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     at
> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:322) 02-09
> 10:07:48.738: E/AndroidRuntime(1713):     ... 30 more 02-09 10:07:48.804:
> I/global(1713): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1110ms. 02-09
> 10:07:49.957: D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_CONCURRENT freed 908K, 51% free
> 3705K/7431K, external 2360K/3860K, paused 2ms+2ms 02-09 10:07:50.242:
> I/global(1713): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 1147ms. 02-09
> 10:07:50.410: D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 598K, 51% free
> 3698K/7431K, external 2360K/3860K, paused 38ms 02-09 10:07:50.574:
> D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 164K, 50% free 3779K/7431K,
> external 2360K/3860K, paused 51ms 02-09 10:07:50.593:
> D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 243K, 50% free 3773K/7431K,
> external 2360K/3860K, paused 15ms 02-09 10:07:50.609:
> D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 47% free 4010K/7431K,
> external 2360K/3860K, paused 16ms 02-09 10:07:50.699:
> D/dalvikvm(1713): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1194K, 49% free 3982K/7687K,
> external 2360K/3860K, paused 2ms+3ms
```

Thanks a lot, I didn't succeed about making my logCat look better, sorry about that.

Here is my class TabsFragment,

<<<<<

```
package fr.partisocialiste.psa.activity;

import fr.partisocialiste.psa.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabsFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener{

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentTabs";
    public static final String TAB_HOLL = "Hollande";
    public static final String TAB_PS = "PS";

    private View mRoot;
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private int mCurrentTab;

    public TabsFragment(){
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_fragment, null);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        setupTabs();
        return mRoot;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
        // manually start loading hollande
        updateTab(TAB_HOLL, R.id.tab_hollande);
    }

    private void setupTabs() {
        mTabHost.setup(); // important!
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_HOLL, R.string.tab_hollande, R.id.tab_hollande));
        mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_PS, R.string.tab_ps, R.id.tab_ps));
    }

    private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "buildTab(): tag=" + tag);

        View indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.tab,
                (ViewGroup) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs), false);
        ((TextView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(labelId);

        TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator);
        tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
        return tabSpec;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if (TAB_HOLL.equals(tabId)) {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_hollande);
            mCurrentTab = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (TAB_PS.equals(tabId)) {
            updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_ps);
            mCurrentTab = 1;
            return;
        }

    }

    private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
            if(TAB_HOLL.equals(tabId)){
//              fm.beginTransaction()
//              .replace(placeholder, new MyListFragment(tabId), tabId)
//              .commit();
            }
            else if(TAB_PS.equals(tabId)){
//              fm.beginTransaction()
//              .replace(placeholder, new MyListFragment(tabId), tabId)
//              .commit();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering what API level do you use here?

Comment: Android 2.2 with the compatibility library, i think that you can use it from API 4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as below

android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment: make
sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that
s public

Check above and make corrections accordingly.

Comment: unfortunatly, the class name exist, is public and has an empty constructor that is public !

Comment: is it calling super constructor

Comment: it wasn't indeed, but doesn't change anything... i've copy paste my tabsFragment class

Comment: Have you any more idea ? I need help on this one :/

Answer (score 0):

I normally use inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_fragment, container, false); but the problem is this:

```
<fragment
        android:name="fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment"...
```

You want

```
<fragment
       class="fr.partisocialite.psa.activity.TabsFragment"...
```

Comment: I sure have tried that, I wrote it in the original post, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. since i wasn't sure if it was either name or class, I try both every time i change something.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have like this warnings before error:

```
05-16 10:08:00.033: W/dalvikvm(1695): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity; (7)
05-16 10:08:00.076: W/dalvikvm(1695): Link of class 'Lmy/fragment/test/FragmentTestActivity;' failed
```

If so, then try:

Configure Java Build Path -> Order And Export tab -> set checkbox android-support-v4.jar

(Maybe need to remove existing one firstly)